# Is there a way to move the x-axis upwards by editing a Stata graph scheme?

Tags: graphics, visualization, stata

Is there a way to change Stata graph themes such that the x-axis coincides with the 0 of the y-axis (so there's no grid line for the 0, just a solid x-axis line)? (Moving the y-axis upwards from the graph example picture attached.) Trying to create  a scheme but struggling to find an option which would do this.
[image: Stata graph using the default graph theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with scheme settings, or you can just note that this is tuneable directly with an option. Consider

```
sysuse auto, clear
scatter trunk weight, plotregion(margin(b=0)) yla(0(5)25)
```

By the way, it's a matter of taste, but many people, especially in the snarkier tail of economics, sneer at those using the default `s2color` scheme, with its tell-tale choice of a blue backdrop. If you like it, well and good, but I'd recommend almost anything else. `s1color` is a simple alternative.

Note: schemes not themes. Themes is the same broad idea introduced later in R, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thank you v much Nick! This is exactly what I want. You don't know of an easy way to achieve this by playing around with scheme settings, do you? Have been giving it a go but can't get the same thing, and it would be very useful in order to make multiple graphs look the same using a custom scheme. Thanks again.

Comment: I had a quick look and couldn't find anything useful.